# Question to understand how sections work

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose that $C$ is a compact Riemann surface o positive genus $g$. Let $L$ a linear bundle on $C$ .
Chosen a divisor $D$ on $C$ we consider the set $L(D)$ that is the tensor product between $L$ and the line bundle $[D]$: $L(D)=L \otimes[D] $

Does it make sense to define the quotien $L(D)/L$?
Due to the definition of $L$ i would say that $L(D)/L$ is trivial but i'm not sure.

The question arises because i'm reading Mumford's notes and i've found a commutative diagram that contains this.
Here the link (diagramm at page 183)
http://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/3612774/Mumford_ThetaCharAlgCurve.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: It would be better if you add the link in your question (rather than give it in your comment). I got confused with the notations twice (and in the end I realized that I was correct in the first time). Please add it and also you can (of course, if you want) modify your question.

Comment: To be clear: if i take $L/L(D)$ this is the set of all sections modulo those that have poles on $D$.  If i take $L(D)/L$, this is $(L \otimes [D] )/L$. Am i right?

Comment: From the exact sequence 
$0 \to \mathcal O_C(-D) \to \mathcal O_C \to \mathcal O_D \to 0, $
we get, tensoring by $L(D):=L \otimes \mathcal O_C(D),$ the exact sequence $0 \to L \to L(D) \to L(D)|_D \to 0.$ With the notations of the above mentioned paper, $L(D)/L := L(D)|_D$

Comment: And if i take $H^0(C,L(D)/L)$ what kind of sections do i get?

Comment: If $D$ is effective, then $H^0(C, L(D)/L)$ is a finite dimensional vector space with dimension equals to the degree of $D.$

Comment: How can i see it ? i know that $H^0(C,L(D)/L)=(L(D)/L)(C)$

Comment: See *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* by *Qing Liu,* Chapter 7, Lemma 3.5. A more appropriate reference is https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kHKaeGEpUDwC&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=properties+of+degree,+gunter+harder&source=bl&ots=kvp_dY4o5M&sig=jPI1gfCDY8QelRehD6FgBTU7MoM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pP8WVaSCEYyguQSQpIDYDg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=properties%20of%20degree%2C%20gunter%20harder&f=false I hope this will help.